# enumerate with circled label

Tags: tikz-pgf, enumerate

Can anyone help me to create a list in which the label is inside the circle? [image]

Above is my text. I create that using `tabular` environment. Now I want to create a new list where the label A, B, C, D is **bold** and **inside a circle**. Also, I want the list to be **align left and quite closed** to the indentation of the question. Thanks a lot for helping.

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tasks,calc}
\settasks{label = \protect\circled{\textbf{\sffamily\Alph*}},
  label-width = 2em,
  label-offset = 2pt,
  item-indent = 2em+2pt}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand*\circled[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{
            \node[shape=circle,draw,inner sep=1pt] (char) {#1};}}
\begin{document}

\noindent
This is some text followed by four options.
\begin{tasks}(2)
\task $\displaystyle\exists x\in\mathbb{R}:\frac{x^2-1}{x-1}=x+1$.
\task $\displaystyle\forall x\in\mathbb{R}:\frac{x^2-1}{x-1}>x+1$.
\task $\displaystyle\forall x\in\mathbb{R}:\frac{x^2-1}{x-1}=x+1$.
\task $\displaystyle\exists x\in\mathbb{R}:\frac{x^2-1}{x-1}>x+1$.
\end{tasks}
\end{document}
```

Comment: yes, thanks a lot. But does this work on ```article``` class?